# Using List Functions to Extract the Middle Section of a String

Tags: parsing, coldfusion

I need to pull out (parse) the middle section of a data record, the typical record is similar to this string:

```
CARY 12345 (Supporting documentation here).
```

What I need to do is pull out just the `12345` portion of the data record. I've been using this CF code:

```
cnumber = '00' & listFirst( listLast( ctic, ' ' ), ' ' );
```

But the results output like this:

```
00(Supporting documentation here).
```

Instead, I would like the output to be:

```
0012345
```

Comment: I think you were looking for `listRest()` rather than `listLast()`.

Comment: ReReplace might be a better approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove characters in <cfoutput> with ReplaceNoCase() ColdFusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965244/remove-characters-in-cfoutput-with-replacenocase-coldfusion)

Comment: RE: possible duplicate: The data record changed since the original question that was answered. So should I just continue again in the original question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're certain that your data would always look like that, and you always want to get the second item, you could do something like:

```
listGetAt(myData,2," ")
```

To pad with zeroes, you can use numberFormat():

```
numberFormat(listGetAt(myData,2," "),"0000000")
```

but this makes a number of assumptions about the format of your data and will break down if it doesn't match.

Comment: Actually your initial comment worked: I think you were looking for listRest() rather than listLast().  The actual code:                                                                               cnumber = listFirst( listRest( cTic, ' ' ), ' ' );

Answer (score 2):

Try Mid and Replace together

```
    <cfoutput>
       <cfset str = Mid("CARY 12345","5", "6")>
       <cfset str = "00"&str>
       <cfset str = Replace(str, " ","","All")>
           #str#
     </cfoutput>
```